# Long Polling System on Server side

Tags: python, django, heroku, websocket

I need a sort of consultation. I am building a web app in django(hosted in heroku) which need to communicate with 100 of embedded devices(writing in C++/C). The embedded devices send data(50kb) to the web app and the web app present this information in a form of graphs.
My concern is , is it wise to build a python polling system(Socket communication) in the server side ?
Or is it Error-prone and I should use services like CloudMQTT?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Do you need to send a continuous response *to* the embedded device, in addition to the success indication?

Comment: yes I do need to send a respond to indicate of success

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you just want to get data from the device to the central server. Why not just do a POST *from* the device *to* the server, return success/failure, and cut the connection? Why the need for polling/long polling?

Comment: because the programmers in the Embedded side only knows to communicate in classic socket communication writing in C and not in Post request which can be done in C/C++.

Comment: any other suggestions? :/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wanna have another project on your hands, it'd be best to use a dedicated library.

This isn't python specific, but I feel like you could achieve your goal relatively easy with a simple ajax request.

Check out [The WebSocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

EDIT:

Upon further reading I found the [Python port of websockets](https://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/)

Comment: The problem is that these devices doesn't have a url or and known ip address which can be access from outside,so How do I communicate with such devices?
The programmer of the embedded side want to ping my url site, I am not sure if this a wise decision.